# InitialContext thrrows exception when trying lookup

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, lookup

I'm pretty new to EJB , and I'm trying to lookup a EJB from the InitialContext , Every thing was working fine , Until I changed the project name and now its giving me this exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system  property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at client.TestingEnt.main(TestingEnt.java:23)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class TestingEnt {

public static void main(String[] args){
    InitialContext ctx=getInitialContext();
    EmployeeManager stub=null;
    try {
        stub = (EmployeeManager) ctx.lookup(getLookupName());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Lookup Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Add new employee

    Employee emp1=new Employee();
    emp1.setFirstName("David");
    emp1.setLastName("Young");
    emp1.setDept("Sales");
    emp1.setSalary(10000);
    stub.addEmployee(emp1);
    System.out.println("Employee no'1 was added");

    Employee emp2=new Employee();
    emp2.setFirstName("Dana");
    emp2.setLastName("Kore");
    emp2.setDept("Finance");
    emp2.setSalary(15000);
    stub.addEmployee(emp2); 
    System.out.println("Employee no'2 was added");
    System.out.println("______________________________");


   private static String getLookupName() {

       String appName = "";

       String moduleName = "EntitiesLab";

       String distinctName = "";

       String beanName = EmployeeManagerBean.class.getSimpleName();

       System.out.println(beanName);

       final String interfaceName = EmployeeManager.class.getName();

       System.out.println(interfaceName);

       String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" +
           distinctName    + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;
       System.out.println(name);
       return name;
   }

public static InitialContext getInitialContext(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    try {
        return new InitialContext(properties);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot generate InitialContext");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

It was working fine before, All I did was change the project name and now it throws the exception. I did change the project name in the lookup method so everything should have worked , So what could I be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with your environment, not with your code (although the code does contain a clue).

Your code tells jndi how to look up the initial context through an environment variable called `org.jboss.ejb.client.naming`. The variable contains a full name of your class, complete with its package name. When you renamed the project, you probably changed the package name as well. Now the environment variable `org.jboss.ejb.client.naming` points to some class that does not exist. You need to change that variable to reference your renamed class name to fix the problem.

Comment: Turns out the jboss-client.jar wasn't present once i changed the project name,